# How to use ASCII characters as tags?

Tags: html

How can I use ASCII characters such as `&#60` (<) and `&gt` (<)  to generate tags? For example if I wanted to use `<strike>` tag that would work but if I use `&ltstrike&gt` would that get rendered as html?

If not are there any other characters that i can use other than <> to generate html code?

Comment: HTML character entities are terminated with semi-colons, so `&gt` should be written `&gt;` (therefore there's no way that `&ltstrike&gt` will produce `<strike>`, it should be written: `&lt;strike&gt;`)

Comment: Why can't you use the standard tags? We might find another solution if we understand your problem.

Comment: Your goal is very unclear.Please [edit]. (Also, HTML doesn't have anything to do with ASCII. Your example of &#60; or &x3C; is [Unicode Character 'LESS-THAN SIGN' (U+003C)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3c/index.htm).)

Comment: @tomBodget can I use any other characters other than <> to create html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. HTML tags must be written using `<` and `>` characters.

HTML escapes, like `&lt;` or `&#60;`, will only display as the literal character. They cannot be used as a substitute for real `<` characters -- the whole point of those escapes is that they *don't* have that effect.

Comment: Hmm I see, are there any other characters that can be used other than <>

Comment: No. I repeat: HTML tags must be written using `<` and `>` characters.